# Netbeans not starting Java DB Server with JDK 1.8.0_40

Tags: java, netbeans-8, javadb

That's my setup:
1) Windows 8.1
2) JDK 1.8.0_40
3) Netbenas 8.0.2

The system was running JDK 1.8.0_31 and everything was working pretty well.
JDK 1.8.0_31 was uninstalled and JDK 1.8.0_40 installed and JAVA_HOME var was
adjusted to reflect the new JDK version, from C:\java\jdk1.8.0_31 to
C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40.

I applied the following changes to my Netbeans:
1) Menu Tools | Libraries: 'Java DB Driver' was changed to reflect the libraries which come with JDK version: C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derby.jar C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar (I'm from Brazil) C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbyclient.jar C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40\db\lib\derbynet.jar
2) 'Services' tab, right-click on 'Java DB', Properties menu item: a) 'Java DB Installation' setup to C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40\db b) Database location is the same when everything was working fine.

In (1) the only difference is in the JDK root dir.

Now when I right-click on 'Java DB' on 'Services' tab nothing happens, no error,
no messages, simply nothing.

If I right-click on any existing Derby connection and choose 'Connect...' a
small windows shows up with the message "Connecting to database, please wait..."
and in the status bar (on the botton of Netbeans main window) there's a message
"Starting the Java DB Server" and that process stays running forever 'cause
nothing happens. I can close the small window, then I try to close the message
on status bar another windows shows up with the message "Are you sure you want
to cancel Starting Java DB Server?". I click "Yes" button and another window
with a wired message "The Java DB server did not start in 0 seconds. Do you want
to wait another 0 seconds?" shows up, I click "No" button and the process of
starting Java DB Server seems to stop.

I appreciate any contributions to get that wired problem solved.

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem. I found a workaround. Just change db provided with Java to the one provided with GlassFish:

1. Make sure you have NetBeans installation with GlassFish (and JavaDB)
2. Open dialog NetBeans → ProjectManager → Services → Databases → JavaDB(right click) → Properties:

   [image: Original path]
3. My screen is from Linux installation. You probably have something like *C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40\db* as *Java DB Installation.*. Change this path to the one from Glassfish. I don't know where it is on Windows, here's mine path:

   [image: Corrected path]

This is only workaround, as I don't know why JavaDB server provided by Oracle with Java >= 1.8.0_40 exits immediate after execution. Probably this is some kind of bug.

Comment: Still actual. Was banging my head against this wall for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on `Mac Os X 10.10.3`, `NetBeans 8.0.2`, `Oracle JDK 8.0.45`

Running `$DERBY_HOME/bin/sysinfo` (or `$JAVA_HOME/db/bin/sysinfo`), I found a previous version of derby library on `/Library/Java/Extension`. I solved the problem removing this files.