# netbeans - java db server doesn't start

Tags: java, netbeans, javadb

I'm trying to use Java DB in netbeans but the server doesn't start. I've tried adding

```
grant {
          permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen";
}
```

but it didn't make any difference. I don't know what causes a problem.
I successfully started the server using cmd but I still cannot connect to the database (the window "connecting to database" pops out but nothing happens, I also don't get any output from Java DB Database Proccess)
Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I found a workaround. Just change db provided with Java to the one provided with GlassFish:

1. Make sure you have NetBeans installation with GlassFish (and JavaDB)
2. Open dialog NetBeans → ProjectManager → Services → Databases → JavaDB(right click) → Properties:

   [image: Original path]
3. My screen is from Linux installation. You probably have something like *C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40\db* as *Java DB Installation.*. Change this path to the one from Glassfish. I don't know where it is on Windows, here's mine path:

   [image: Corrected path]

This is only workaround, as I don't know why JavaDB server provided by Oracle with Java >= 1.8.0_40 exits immediate after execution. Probably this is some kind of bug.

This may be duplicated issue ([Netbeans not starting Java DB Server with JDK 1.8.0_40](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196489/netbeans-not-starting-java-db-server-with-jdk-1-8-0-40/29714528)), but I am not sure.

Comment: This is the strangest thing. I had it working with Glassfish 5.1.0 until yesterday when it suddenly stopped working. I can't figure out why. I've tried removing and re-downloading Glassfish (I've tried Glassfish 5.1.0, Glassfish 3.1.22) but it didn't help. I tried downloading Derby from the Apache website (10.15.2.0) and setting that, still won't start. It gets stuck on "Connecting to Database, please wait..." but it never connects. When I do `Java DB -> Start server` I see this in the output: https://pastebin.com/AwUDBxZ2 . And yet it's working fine on a different machine...

Answer (score 0):

Try the grant code as:

```
grant{ 
   permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen,resolve"; 
};
```

Also, read [Here (click)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u51-relnotes-2085002.html) about the related bug(fix) in the JDK tool

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently with netbeans 8.2 and JDK 8. I'm writing the solution here for future references.

- Go to https://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.14.2.0.cgi and download the latest version of derby driver (today is 10.14.2.0).
- Extract it and place the extracted folder in your %JAVA_HOME%. The result will be something like this: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\db-derby-10.14.2.0-bin.
- Inside netbeans, in the services tab, right click on Java DB > Properties and configure the location of your new derby driver as below.

[image]

- Start again the Java DB server to see it working.